# Having issues with List.Contains - Not loading

Tags: excel, powerquery

Oi,

So i'm having issues with the List.Contains (x,x)=false function.

**Context**
I have 32 Excel files where i retrieve data from in a first query, this data gets filtered so only the columns needed (Each of those 32 Excel files is about 2MB) - This query then gets transformed into a "list" (ListofJustifWBS) so i only have the WBS's of that particular Query.

I also have another query, where i import a huge data excel file including WBS's - Actuals - Best estimates,...

What i want to do is : only keep the WBS's from the second Query that are not included in the first query.
The code i'm using is `= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each (List.Contains(ListOfJustifWBS,[WBS])=false))`

Whenever i run the query in the editor, the data get processed.. However, when i track the "progress" in the bottom right cornor i see all 32 excel file getting progressed, but excel sometimes "retrieved" (?) 20MB worth of data in each excel file while the excel file itself is only 2MB?
Whenever i try to run the query in an Excel Sheet tabl, Excel goes "Not responding".

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you replace

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each (List.Contains(ListOfJustifWBS,[WBS])=false))
```

with

```
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"WBS"},  Table.FromList(ListOfJustifWBS ), {"Column1"}, "ListOfJustifWBS", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded ListOfJustifWBS" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "ListOfJustifWBS", {"Column1"}, {"Column1.1"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded ListOfJustifWBS", each ([Column1.1] = null))
```

is this any faster ?